# NSDate is null for a specific date

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting null string for a specific date, i.e. 13/03/2013. Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"12/03/2013 5:47:00 AM"];
NSDate *myDate1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"13/03/2013 6:25:48 AM"];           

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSString *datestr = [df stringFromDate:myDate];
NSString *datestr1 = [df stringFromDate:myDate1];
NSLog(@"date object %@,%@",datestr,datestr1);
```

Comment: myDate1 is in the 13th month?

Comment: There is no month 13.  Perhaps you meant to use dd/MM/yyyy instead of MM/dd/yyyy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is Your date format is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a`. And you added a date like: `13/03/2013 6:25:48 AM`.

There is only 12 month, no month for 13.

Change the format to: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a`

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you take a look into the standards of date format. [Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"12/03/2013 5:47:00 AM"];
    NSDate *myDate1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"13/03/2013 6:25:48 AM"];  

    [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSString *datestr = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
    NSString *datestr1 = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate1];
    NSLog(@"date object %@,%@",datestr,datestr1);
```

Comment: @shivam The error is where you form the date. And also you don't need to create new dateFormatter to form dateString in a different format.

Comment: @shivam By default NSDateFormatter will have the localTimezone. The above mentioned code assumes your initial dateString is in local timezone. If it's not you need to explicitly set the timezone before converting to date.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no 13'th month.

13/03/2013 is an invalid date,since you use formatter as MM/dd//yyyy.

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"12/03/2013 5:47:00 AM"];
NSDate *myDate1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"13/03/2013 6:25:48 AM"];

NSLog(@"%@",myDate1);


NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSString *datestr = [df stringFromDate:myDate];
NSString *datestr1 = [df stringFromDate:myDate1];



NSLog(@"date object %@,%@",datestr,datestr1);
```